# Cython extension class: How do I expose methods in the auto-generated C struct?

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have existing C++ code that defines some classes I need to use, but I need to be able to send those classes to Python code.  Specifically, I need to create class instances in C++, create Python objects to serve as wrappers for these C++ objects, then pass these Python objects to Python code for processing.  This is just one piece of a larger C++ program, so it needs to be done ultimately in C++ using the C/Python API.

To make my life easier, I have used Cython to define extension classes (cdef classes) that serve as the Python wrappers for my C++ objects.  I am using the typical format where the cdef class contains a pointer to the C++ class, which is then initialized when the cdef class instance is created.  Since I also want to be able to replace the pointer if I have an existing C++ object to wrap, I have added methods to my cdef classes to `accept()` the C++ object and take its pointer.  My other cdef classes successfully use the `accept()` method in Cython, for example when one object owns another.

Here is a sample of my Cython code:

`MyCPlus.pxd`

```
cdef extern from "MyCPlus.h" namespace "mynamespace":
    cdef cppclass MyCPlus_Class:
        MyCPlus_Class() except +
```

`PyModule.pyx`

```
cimport MyCPlus
from libcpp cimport bool

cdef class Py_Class [object Py_Class, type PyType_Class]:
    cdef MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class* thisptr
    cdef bool owned

    cdef void accept(self, MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class &indata):
        if self.owned:
            del self.thisptr
        self.thisptr = &indata
        self.owned = False

    def __cinit__(self):
        self.thisptr = new MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class()
        self.owned = True

    def __dealloc__(self):
        if self.owned:
            del self.thisptr
```

The problem comes when I try to access the `accept()` method from C++.  I tried using the `public` and `api` keywords on my cdef class and on the `accept()` method, but I cannot figure out how to expose this method in the C struct in Cython's auto-generated `.h` file.  No matter what I try, the C struct looks like this:

`PyModule.h` (auto-generated by Cython)

```
struct Py_Class {
  PyObject_HEAD
  struct __pyx_vtabstruct_11PyModule_Py_Class *__pyx_vtab;
  mynamespace::MyCPlus_Class *thisptr;
  bool owned;
};
```

I also tried typing the `self` input as a `Py_Class`, and I even tried forward-declaring `Py_Class` with the `public` and `api` keywords.  I also experimented with making `accept()` a static method.  Nothing I've tried works to expose the `accept()` method so that I can use it from C++.  I did try accessing it through `__pyx_vtab`, but I got a compiler error, "invalid use of incomplete type".  I have searched quite a bit, but haven't seen a solution to this.  Can anyone help me?  Please and thank you!

Comment: `static void __pyx_f_8PyModule_8Py_Class_accept(struct __pyx_obj_8PyModule_Py_Class *__pyx_v_self, mynamespace::MyCPlus_Class &__pyx_v_indata); /* proto*/` looks plausible as something you could use.

Comment: @DavidW, That might work for a time, but I'm really looking for a solution of how to tell Cython to put this method into my API.  The line you quoted above is buried deep in the auto-generated `.cpp` file, and it could change unexpectedly.  I need a more maintainable solution.  Thank you for the attempt, though.

Comment: The other thing you could *try* is declaring `accept()` in *both* the `pxd` and `pyx` files – if you have it as a fully declared class method (not just a `extern` method prototype to be exposed) and Cython generates an  correspondingly named accessible method, it’d be yours to either call or override

Comment: @fish2000 The `accept()` method is not part of my original C++ class (and I can't add it) so there would be no reason to put in in the `pxd`.  What I need is for it to be included in the C-struct of my extension class so I can create an extension class wrapper for my C++ object that I can then send to Python.  It's funny because Cython does put in that `__pyx_vtab`, but that seems to be for Cython use only, not for external C/C++ code.  I'm thinking that Cython just isn't designed to do this yet.

Answer (score 2):

As you pointed in your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906296/cython-extension-class-how-do-i-expose-methods-in-the-auto-generated-c-struct#comment57857800_34906296), it does seem that the `__pyx_vtab` member is for Cython use only, since it doesn't even define the struct type for it in the exported header(s).

Adding to your response, one approach could also be:

```
cdef api class Py_Class [object Py_Class, type Py_ClassType]:
    ...
    cdef void accept(self, MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class &indata):
        ...  # do stuff here
    ...


cdef api void (*Py_Class_accept)(Py_Class self, MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class &indata)
Py_Class_accept = &Py_Class.accept
```

Basically, we define a function pointer and set it to the extension's method we want to expose. This is not that much different to your response's `cdef`'d function; the main difference would be that we can define our methods as usual in the class definition without having to duplicate functionality or method/function calls to another function to expose it. One caveat is that we would've to define our function pointer's signature almost verbatim to the method's one in addition to the `self`'s extension type (in this case) and etc; then again this also applies for regular functions.

Do note that I tried this up on a C-level Cython `.pyx` file, I haven't and do not intent to test it on a CPP implementation file. But hopefully this might work just as fine, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

This is not really a solution, but I came up with a workaround for my problem.  I am still hoping for a solution that allows me to tell Cython to expose the `accept()` method to C++.

My workaround is that I wrote a separate function for my Python class (not a method).  I then gave the `api` keyword both to my Python class and to the new function:

```
cdef api class Py_Class [object Py_Class, type PyType_Class]:
(etc.)

cdef api Py_Class wrap_MyCPlusClass(MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class &indata):
    wrapper = Py_Class()
    del wrapper.thisptr
    wrapper.thisptr = &indata
    wrapper.owned = False
    return wrapper
```

This gets a little unwieldy with the number of different classes I need to wrap, but at least Cython puts the function in the API where it is easy to use:

```
struct Py_Class* wrap_MyCPlusClass(mynamespace::MyCPlusClass &);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use `cpdef` instead of `cdef` when declaring `accept`. See [the docs](http://docs.cython.org/src/reference/language_basics.html#callable-from-both-python-and-c):

> Callable from Python and C
>   * Are declared with the cpdef statement.
>   * Can be called from anywhere, because it uses a little Cython magic.
>   * Uses the faster C calling conventions when being called from other Cython code.

Try that!

Comment: I don't need to access `accept()` from Python; only from Cython and C++ (I did verify it works in Cython already).  I did try this just for the heck of it, but Cython gives an error because `MyCPlus.MyCPlus_Class` is not a Python object.  Thanks for the attempt though.

Comment: Oh aha my error – just curious, if you were to try the same again without the explicit type declaration, what do you get? I feel like type annotation information in `pyx` files is supposed to be optional and treated as “hinting” but I could be misremembering that completely.

Comment: For Python-accessible functions, I use static typing in `pyx` files to force Python to do automatic conversion on inputs (which also provides a certain level of type-checking).  For C-accessible functions, Cython needs to know how to declare the function, so you can use static typing to specify.  If you don't specify, I think it assumes something is a Python object.  If you specify a Cython extension class, then you need to also declare that class `public` or `api`, else your compiler won't know what it is.  That is why I tried putting these keywords on both the class and the method.