# How to call a cpdef method from C

Tags: cython

I have a public class with a method defined with cpdef. According to cython documentation, this can be called from C. However the generated header does not have any C/C++ functions/method generated for this.

```
cdef public class Model[type ModelType, object Model]:                                                           
  cdef ModelContext *modelContext                                                                                
  cpdef calculate(self):                                                                                           
    print 'calculate called on Modell'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cython extension class: How do I expose methods in the auto-generated C struct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906296/cython-extension-class-how-do-i-expose-methods-in-the-auto-generated-c-struct)

Comment: I realise there are some differences small differences between the two questions but I think the answer is basically the same. I think their "workround" answer (http://stackoverflow.com/a/34928793/4657412) is probably the best you can do. I'd simplify it a little and have your non-class function just call your class function: `cpdef public calculate(Model m): return m.calculate()`