# How to create a public cython function that can receive c++ struct/instance or python object as parameter?

Tags: python, c++, struct, cython

My Rectangle.h

```
namespace shapes {
    class Rectangle {
    public:
        int x0, y0, x1, y1;
        Rectangle();
        Rectangle(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1);
        ~Rectangle();
        int getArea();
    };
}
```

My Rectangle.cpp

```
#include "Rectangle.h"
namespace shapes {
  Rectangle::Rectangle() { }
    Rectangle::Rectangle(int X0, int Y0, int X1, int Y1) {
        x0 = X0;
        y0 = Y0;
        x1 = X1;
        y1 = Y1;
    }
    Rectangle::~Rectangle() { }
    int Rectangle::getArea() {
        return (x1 - x0) * (y1 - y0);
    }
}
```

My rect.pyx

```
# distutils: language = c++
# distutils: sources = Rectangle.cpp

cdef extern from "Rectangle.h" namespace "shapes":
    cdef cppclass Rectangle:
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getArea()

cdef class PyRectangle:
    cdef Rectangle c_rect
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def get_area(self):
        return self.c_rect.getArea()

cdef public int cythonfunc(PyRectangle py_rect):
    result = py_rect.get_area()
    return result
```

My main.cpp

```
#include <Python.h>

#include "rect.h"

#include "Rectangle.h"
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int result;
  Py_Initialize();

  PyInit_rect();
  shapes::Rectangle c_rect = shapes::Rectangle(0,0,2,1);
  result = cythonfunc(c_rect);
  std::cout<<result<<"\n";

  Py_Finalize();

  return 0;
}
```

My Makefile

```
all:
        cython3 --cplus rect.pyx
        c++ -g -O2 -c rect.cpp -o rect.o `python3-config --includes`
        c++ -g -O2 -c Rectangle.cpp -o Rectangle.o `python3-config --includes`
        c++ -g -O2 -c main.cpp -o main.o `python3-config --includes`
        c++ -g -O2 -o rect Rectangle.o rect.o main.o `python3-config --libs`

clean:
        rm -f rect rect.cpp rect.h *.o
```

My problem is related to the "cythonfunc" in rect.pyx. This is intended to be a public function that can be called from main with a rectangle struct/object as parameter, and return an area to main.cpp.

I've tried c struct and python object, both does not work for me. If I use this codes, the compiler gives an error of

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    def __cinit__(self, int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1):
        self.c_rect = Rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1)
    def get_area(self):
        return self.c_rect.getArea()

cdef public int cythonfunc(PyRectangle py_rect):
                          ^
------------------------------------------------------------

rect.pyx:19:27: Function declared public or api may not have private types
```

So I added "public" to PyRectangle, but got another error:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
        Rectangle() except +
        Rectangle(int, int, int, int) except +
        int x0, y0, x1, y1
        int getArea()

cdef public class PyRectangle:
    ^
------------------------------------------------------------

rect.pyx:12:5: Type object name specification required for 'public' C class
```

If I change cythonfunc to:

```
cdef public int cythonfunc(Rectangle c_rect):
    result = c_rect.getArea()
    return result
```

I got error of:

```
In file included from main.cpp:3:0:
rect.h:21:42: warning: ‘cythonfunc’ initialized and declared ‘extern’
 __PYX_EXTERN_C DL_IMPORT(int) cythonfunc(shapes::Rectangle);
                                          ^
rect.h:21:42: error: ‘shapes’ has not been declared
main.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
main.cpp:17:29: error: ‘cythonfunc’ cannot be used as a function
   result = cythonfunc(c_rect);
                             ^
```

I can only success with passing separate x0, y0, x1, y1 as parameter to cythonfunc. Is there a correct way to passing a cpp struct/object or python object as parameter to a cython public function?

Comment: Just to be sure "cdef pulbic class PyRectangle:" - Is the that a typo?

Comment: Yes, It is! Thank you for figuring it out, I've updated the right error message correspondingly.

Comment: Does this not solve it? http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html

Comment: No. At least I can't find enough information to accomplish it. I've found another link that most approaching to this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906296/cython-extension-class-how-do-i-expose-methods-in-the-auto-generated-c-struct After thoroughly searching, I realize cython interfacing ability with c++ is not very powerful.

Answer (score 5):

With respect to your second attempt (which is probably the more sensible way of calling it from C++, although I'd pass by reference):

```
cdef public int cythonfunc(Rectangle c_rect):
    result = c_rect.getArea()
    return result
```

the issue is that it doesn't know what `Rectangle` is, since the Cython generated `rect.h` doesn't include `Rectangle.h`. The easiest way to fix this is to swap the order of the includes in `main.cpp`:

```
#include "Rectangle.h" // this one is now first
#include "rect.h"
```

The error "shapes has not been declared" was telling you this...

---

With respect you your first attempt, you were right that you have to make `PyRectangle` public. To do so you also need to specify a "type object name" as Cython tells you. You do so as shown [here](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/extension_types.html#public-and-external-extension-types) (although it honestly isn't hugely clear...):

```
cdef public class PyRectangle [object c_PyRect, type c_PyRect_t]:
    # ... as before
```

This ensures that PyRectangle is available to C/C++ as `struct c_PyRect` (and so the `cythonfunc` signature is `int cythonfunc(struct c_PyRect *);`.)

Also, the Python `TypeObject` defining `PyRectangle` is available as `c_PyRect_t`, but you don't need that.

Comment: FYI I wrote this solution up at https://github.com/pelson/calling_publicly_declared_cython_from_c/tree/e4edfc9543876dda050e6c029e03e1e9b835ad1f.